# How to parse data using Alamofire when parent and child have same data?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I am using Alamofire for calling and parsing json data but issue is that response is not correct. parent and child have same data so parser changed the ids in parsing and number of items get reduced. Data below is the json which i want to parse using model

```
{
"error": false,
"message": "",
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "parent_id": null,
        "name": "Ink Cartridge",
        "notes": null,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "parent_id": 1,
                "name": "Colored",
                "notes": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "parent_id": null,
        "name": "Toner Cartridge",
        "notes": null,
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "parent_id": null,
        "name": "Combo",
        "notes": null,
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "parent_id": null,
        "name": "Combo Set",
        "notes": null,
        "children": []
    }
]
```

}

and i am using this Alamofire and SwiftyJSON libraries

```
Alamofire.request(ServerAPI.getCategories()).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
            print(swiftyJsonVar)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you should be using Codable as it makes this much easier. 
Build these structs, the parent struct goes through the data using the constant name so for example let id, will get you the "id" part of the data. I then built another struct so that when it goes through children, it will do the same thing inside using that struct.

```
  struct Parent: Codable {

   let id: Int
   let parent_id: Int?
   let name: String
   let notes: String?
   let children: [Child]?

  }

  struct Child: Codable {

      let id: Int
      let parent_id: Int?
      let name: String
      let notes: String?
  }
```

then you need a var to hold this data:

```
 var completeData = [Parent]()
```

and in your call:

```
      do {
let dataParsed = try JSONDecoder().decode([Parent].self, from: data
 self.completeData = dataParsed

} catch {
print(error)
}
```

and to access it, you should be able to do

```
var accessingID = self.completeData[0].id
```

and for the child:

```
var accessingChild = self.completeData[0].children.id
```

I'm not sure how you want the data so you may want to mess around with the way you handle arrays, and I haven't been able to test but It should be along these lines.

Remember in the structs you need to use `?` if its possible that the value will be null. This method also does not use Alamofire or SwiftyJSON as Codable makes it much more swifty and convenient to do this kind of thing using structs.